# How to change the home menu in bottom navigation layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have added three menus in `BottomNavigationLayout`

How can I open Center menu by default on startup?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    loadFragment(new ProfileFragment());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I used this to load the fragment and it also loads fragment associated with the center menu but on bottom navigation the first menu is selected.

I hope you understand my problem. if not then check the Clash Royale. in this game, the battle layout is the first pop-up at startup as well as battle menu selected in the bottom navigation.

If anyone knows how to do this please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Go for This mate ! Just Copy and paste in your editor and there you go!**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
 //   loadFragment(new ProfileFragment()); Removed this line

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
// Added this line
navigation.setSelectedItemId(bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(1).getItemId()); 
}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onCreate()` method call that fragment which you want to open first at time of app launching.

When you tap on bottom menus you are performing some action for change the color of menu with fragment, Put that fragment on `onCreate` of the Activity with actions, So when by default when app launches it will show you your desired fragment.

Here is reference :

```
 HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment().newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, homeFragment)
                .commit();
```

Full Code Here :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    loadFragment(new ProfileFragment());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

     HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment().newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, homeFragment)
                .commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your Mainactivity

```
 navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_notifications);  // Pass your menu id which you want to selected first
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your mid tab as selected item

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tab2);

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.tab1:
                loadFragment(new ProfileFragment1());
                return true;
            case R.id.tab2:
                loadFragment(new ProfileFragment2());
                return true;
            case R.id.tab3:
                loadFragment(new ProfileFragment3());
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```